# Problems with url routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I have problems with url routing.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "MapCategory", "Blog/{CategoryId}/{CategoryName}", "~/Blog.aspx", false);

routes.MapPageRoute(
    "contact", "contact.aspx", "~/contacts.aspx");
```

First rounting (MapCategory) doesn't works. On localhost works great but online I get the error: *404 - File or directory not found*. Second rounting works both on server and on localhost.

How can I fix it?

Edit:

Ok, I found the problem. I am using *HttpUtility.UrlEncode* to create the link

> NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Blog/" + Eval("ID")+"/"+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
>   Eval("Category").ToString()) > %>'

So, If category is for example *Three o'clock* the result will be *sitename.ro/Blog/22/Three+O%27clock*.
If I remove +,% characters works.

Comment: And what URL are you trying?

Comment: Link looks like:  http://www.sitename.ro/Blog/22/title